# Does there exist a Banach space with no complemented closed subspaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that every Hilbert space can be decomposed as the direct sum of two non-trivial closed subspaces, eg. taking the kernel and range of any non-trivial bounded projection. But I don't know what happens in Banach spaces.

Does there exist a Banach space $B$ with no complemented closed subspaces? In other words, such that there do not exist closed subspaces $U,V\subset B$ with $B=U\oplus V$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementedSubspace.html has an example.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented

Comment: [Newman's paper from 1960](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-01/S0002-9939-1961-0120524-X/S0002-9939-1961-0120524-X.pdf)

Comment: Aren't these examples of a specific closed subspace which is not complemented? I want an example of a space for which every closed subspace is not complemented.

Comment: Pick a nontrivial functional $\ell \in X^*$ and some $v\in X$ so that $\ell(v)=1$. Then $X = \ker \ell \oplus \langle v\rangle.$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finite-dimensional subspaces are always complemented; this follows from [the Hahn–Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

*Proof.* Let $F$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of a Banach space $X$ and let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a basis for $F$. Choose $f_1, \ldots, f_n\in F^*$ to be the coordinate functionals for the basis $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. Use the Hahn–Banach theorem to extend $f_j$ to bounded linear functionals on $X$; call any such extension $f_j$ too ($j\leqslant n$). Set

$$Px = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle f_j, x\rangle x_j\quad (x\in X).$$

Then $P$ is a projection with ${\rm im}\, P=F$. ${ \rm \square}$

The non-trivial variant of the question is really about the possibility of non-trivial decompositions into subspaces which are both infinite-dimensional (the spaces which lack this property exist and are called [indecomposable Banach spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72321/decomposable-banach-spaces)). There is a whole industry concerning such spaces and there exist even spaces with a stronger property, *i.e.*, there are spaces whose all infinite-dimensional suspaces are indecomposale (the so-called [hereditarily indecomposable spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74171/hereditarily-indecomposable-banach-spaces-and-separable-quotient-problem)).

There are [examples of compact, Hausdorff spaces $K$ for which the Banach space $C(K)$ is indecomposale](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2916). (Of course such spaces cannot be hereditarily indecomposale as $C(K)$ always contains a copy of $c_0$ unless $K$ is finite.)

[This](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=MEMO-170-806) is a nice introduction to hereditarily indecomposale spaces.