# If a subspace is not complemented then the identity map can't be extended

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, $Y \subset X$ a closed subspace.
>   $Y$ is called *complemented* if there is a closed subspace $Z \subset X$ such that $X =Y \oplus Z$ as topological vector spaces.
>
> Show that if a closed subspace $Y$ is not complemented, then the identity map on $Y$ can not be extended to a continuous linear function on $X$.

Hi, I think I should do this by contradiction, but I don't know how, I wish you could help me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the identity map $\iota\colon Y\to X$ can be extended to a bounded linear operator $P\colon X\to Y$. Then $P$ is an idempotent. Indeed, for $x\in X$ we have $Px\in Y$ and so $PPx=\iota Px=Px$. Thus, $P$ is a bounded projection with ${\rm im}\, P = Y$. Let $Z = {\rm im}\, (I_X - P)$. Then $Z$ is closed and $X=Y\oplus Z$ as $I_X = P + I_X - P$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but why is Z closed?

Comment: I've already noticed that it's because Z is the kernel of P, thank you so much!