# Is there an analogue for the orthogonal complement in a space with no inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

If we have a Hilbert space $X$ and a closed subspace $M \subset X$, then using the projection theorem we can canonically find $M^\perp$ such that $X = M \oplus M^\perp$.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do an analogue to this in any topological vector space.  Specifically, given a space $X$ and a closed $M \subset X$, can we decompose $X$ into $M \oplus \tilde{M}$ for some $\tilde{M}$ in a canonical way? Maybe this is a dumb question but it's not immediately clear to me that we can even complete a basis of $M$ to a basis of $X$.

Comment: Briefly "no" even if $X$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: No. There are banach spaces with closed, noncomplemented subspaces. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented), say. In fact, the answer is "no" in a much deeper sense: If $X$ is a banach space where every closed subspace has an orthogonal complement, then actually $X$ is hilbert. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176497/banach-space-with-non-complemented-subspace).