# Closed Subspace of a Banach Space with a Non-closed Linear Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

What is an example of a closed subspace of a Banach space whose linear complement (direct sum decomposition) is not closed?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

Note that "linear complement" is not unique. Anyway, if $L$ is a closed subspace of $X$ having a closed linear complement $M$ then $L$ is (topologically) complemented, i.e. there is a continuous linear projection onto $L$. This follows from the open mapping theorem: $L\times M\to X$, $(\ell,m)\mapsto \ell+m$ is a bijective continuous linear operator between Banach spaces hence its inverse is continuous.

An example of a closed subspace without closed complement is thus $c_0 \subseteq \ell^\infty$.

Comment: How do I see that the "linear complement" is not unique?

Comment: A linear complement of $L$ is another subspace $M$ with $L\cap M=\{0\}$ and $L+M$ is the whole space. For the subspace $L=\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ *every* line through the origin and different from $L$ is a linear complement.

Comment: Right. All of the subspaces of lines different from L are isomorphic, so it's unique up to iso?

Comment: Yes for *closed* complements in the case of Banach spaces. Every closed complement of $L$ is isomorphic to the quotient $X/L$.

Comment: Can you give an example of an "open complement" that is not unique up to iso?

Comment: Subspaces are not *doors*: Non-closed subspaces need not be open.