# Counterexample of $X = M \oplus N$, where $X$ is normed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We need to find a counter example for $X = M \oplus N$ , i.e. we have $X$ given normed space and $M$ is closed subspace of $X$ , then there is no **closed** subspace $N$ such as $X=M\oplus N$.

Obviously ,  $N $ can't be finite dimensional , so complement of M should be infinite dimensional and open. 
I've thought to consider $C[0,1]$ but what about $M$ set? Maybe it's good to take some special functions like $\{ \sin(kx), \cos(kx) \}$?

Comment: $M$ is not $X\setminus N$. How do you conclude that $M$ is open if $N$ is f.d.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented?rq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy my bad, I guessed that N should be open. It may be not open nor closed

Comment: I think the most common example is that $c_0(\Bbb N)$ is closed without a complement in $\ell^\infty(\Bbb N)$.