# Banach space is product of quotient space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

Motivation: If $a$ and $b \ne 0$ are real numbers, then $a = b \cdot (a / b)$.

Question: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M \subset X$ a closed subspace. Then, the quotient space $X / M$ is also a Banach space. Do we have
$$
X = M \times (X / M)
$$
in any sense?

(For example, "$\times$" could denote the product Banach space and "$=$" could mean "isomorphic".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a subspace $M$ is called ["complemented"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace)

If $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$, and there exists another closed subspace $N$ such that $X = M \oplus N$, then $N$ is isomorphic to $X/M$.  [Here, I mean that the map $M \oplus N \to X$ defined by $(m,n) \mapsto m+n$ is a homeomorphism from $M \oplus N$ onto $X$.  The topology in $M \oplus N$ is the Cartesian product topology.]

Not all subspaces in a Banach space are complemented, but many common ones are.  Of course in Hilbert space, every subspace is complemented.  Also: finite-dimensional subspaces are complemented.

An example of a subspace that is not complemented: $c_0 \subset l^\infty$ is not compemented.

More difficult to prove, but true: if $X$ is a Banach space and every closed subspace is complemented, then $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that $N$ is isomorphic to $X / M$.

Answer (score 2):

A closed subspace $M$ that satisfies $X\approx M\times N$ for some other closed subspace $N$, is said to be *complemented*.

It is a fact that some Banach spaces have closed subspaces that are not complemented. See [Example of a closed subspace of a Banach space which is not complemented?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented?rq=1)