# Direct complement of subspace (infinite dimansional vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

One can easily prove, that in finite dimensional vector space $V$ for every subspace $U$ there always exists a direct complement. It seems to me that it is not the case in infinite dimensional vector spaces. 
**I wonder if there is any example of some infinite dimensional vector space $V$ (normed) and its subspace $U$ that $U$ doesn't have a direct complement?** 
I want to emphasize that I use the following definition of subspace:

> *Subspace* is a linear topological space.

Theorem which comes to mind:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $W$ its **closed** subspace. Than there exists an orthogonal complement to W, i. e. $H = W  \oplus W^{\perp}.$

So it seems like even in Hilbert space the subspace should be closed to have a direct complement.

Comment: You can come up with an example in Hilbert Space where $U$ is not closed. (E.g take the space of finitely supported sequences in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: If you assume the subspace to be closed, then this has already been asked before and the examples are quite non-trivial.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented?rq=1)